# How to get the selected item's ID from dropdown and send to sqlite android?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I have an Autocomplete textview list where I am populating data from SQLite. When I am selecting one name from the list I want to get the ID/primary key of that particular name and then insert it to the database when a button is clicked. How do I do that?
This is my code by which I am populating data in the Autocomplete text view.

```
package com.example.user.paperflyv0;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class NewOrder extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] executive_num_list;
    public static final String MERCHANT_NAME = "Merchant Name";
    private String EXECUTIVE_URL = "http://paperflybd.com/executiveList.php";
    private String INSERT_URL = "http://192.168.0.117/new/insertassign.php";
    //private String MERCHANT_URL= "http://192.168.0.117/new/merchantlistt.php";
    private String MERCHANT_URL = "http://paperflybd.com/merchantAPI.php";
    private AssignExecutiveAdapter assignExecutiveAdapter;
    List<AssignManager_ExecutiveList> executiveLists;
    List<AssignManager_Model> assignManager_modelList;
    Database database;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_order);
        database = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        database.getWritableDatabase();
        executiveLists = new ArrayList<>();
        assignManager_modelList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Fetching email from shared preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF, "Not Available");
        String user = username.toString();
        getallmerchant();
        getallexecutives();

        final AutoCompleteTextView actv_m_name = findViewById(R.id.auto_m_name);
        final AutoCompleteTextView actv_exe_name = findViewById(R.id.auto_exe_name);
        final EditText count = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.btn_assign);

        List<String> merchantnames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> executivenames = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int z = 0; z < assignManager_modelList.size(); z++) {
            merchantnames.add(assignManager_modelList.get(z).getM_names());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewOrder.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, merchantnames);
        /*       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);*/
        actv_m_name.setAdapter(adapter);


        for (int k = 0; k < executiveLists.size(); k++) {
            executivenames.add(executiveLists.get(k).getExecutive_name());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NewOrder.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, executivenames);
        /*       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);*/
        actv_exe_name.setAdapter(adapter1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                database.insertneworder(actv_m_name.getText().toString(),actv_exe_name.getText().toString(),count.getText().toString());
            }
        });



        }



    private void getallmerchant() {
        try {

            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = database.get_merchantlist(sqLiteDatabase);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String merchantName = c.getString(0);
                String merchantCode = c.getString(1);
                String assigned = c.getString(2);

                AssignManager_Model todaySummary = new AssignManager_Model(merchantName, merchantCode, assigned);
                assignManager_modelList.add(todaySummary);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void getallexecutives() {
        try {

            SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = database.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = database.get_executivelist(sqLiteDatabase);
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String empName = c.getString(0);
                String empCode = c.getString(1);
                AssignManager_ExecutiveList assignManager_executiveList = new AssignManager_ExecutiveList(empName, empCode);
                executiveLists.add(assignManager_executiveList);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

override the onItemClick method and check as follows

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int pos,long arg3) {
   String selectedText = (String) av.getItemAtPosition(pos);
  //or av.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
}
```

Comment: just go through the following resources   [link](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)

Comment: yes i have got the selected item. and showing it to a toast. Then how do i get the primary key of that selected item? should i run a database query?

Answer (score 0):

When working with SQLiteDatabase, it is best to use SQLiteOpenHelper class.

```
    package com.homemedia.home.stackanswers;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "homemedia.db";
public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //create your tables here
}
public void addValues(String values){
    //now get writable db here
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //Use content values to enable you enter the values to db
    ContentValues cvalues = new ContentValues();
    cvalues.put("name", values);
    db.insert("tablenamehere", null, cvalues);
    //
}
public ArrayList<String> getValues(String queryCriteria){
    //now get readable db here
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> itemValues = new ArrayList<>();
    //use cursor to query db
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from tablename", null);
    cursor .moveToFirst(); //moves to 1st positon
    //goes through all items
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        // get particular values here and add to arraylist
        itemValues.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("columnin table")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return itemValues; //if you need int values, put int ArrayList<int>
}
public ArrayList<Integer> empIDs(String criteria){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Integer> itemValues = new ArrayList<>();
    //use cursor to query db
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from tablename WHERE columnValue = criteria ", null);
    cursor .moveToFirst(); //moves to 1st positon
    //goes through all items
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        // get particular values here and add to arraylist
        itemValues.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("primarykey col")));
        //if getting integer is difficult, get as string and convert to int
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return itemValues;
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

Then in main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DBHelper mydb;
ArrayList<String> mylist;
ArrayList<Integer> myIDs;
Spinner myspinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mydb =  new DBHelper(this);
    myIDs = mydb.empIDs("search criteria");
    mylist = mydb.getValues("search Criteria");
    // to add info
    mydb.addValues("value to be added");
myspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String stringId = String.valueOf(myIDs.get(position));
        mydb.addValues(stringId);
    }
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: In your case; use onItemClickListener